# SQL select statement with count of conditional data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to conditionally return column data using a SQL select statement. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

The output should look like this:

```
REP_START_YEAR  UNIVERSITY_CODE     STUDENT_OEN     OEN_COUNT
2012            UNIVERSITYA         999999999       3
2012            UNIVERSITYA         000000000       0
2012            UNIVERSITYA         Other           2105
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
select enrol.Rep_Start_Year, uni.university_code,  enrol.student_OEN, count(*) as Invalid_OEN_Count

from (select enrol.Rep_Start_Year, uni.university_code, enrol.student_OEN, CASE WHEN enrol.student_OEN  not in ('999999999','000000000')
                            THEN 'Other'
                          ELSE enrol.student_OEN
                          END as student_OEN
from edcs_unistat.ustat_enrolment_data enrol) 

inner join    edcs_unistat.uni_institution_type uniinst
on        enrol.uni_institution_type_ID = uniinst.uni_institution_type_id

inner join    
(select u.UNIVERSITY_ID,
    (case 
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'DOMC' then 'CARL'
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'NOSM-LAKE' then 'NOSM'
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'NOSM-LAUR' then 'NOSM'
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'LAUR-ALGM' then 'ALGM'
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'LAUR-HRST' then 'HRST'
        when U.UNIVERSITY_CODE = 'DOMC' then 'CARL'
        else U.UNIVERSITY_CODE 
     end) as university_code
from edcs_core.university u) uni
on          uniinst.university_id = uni.university_id

inner join  edcs_unistat.reg_status_type regstatus
on          enrol.reg_status_type_id = regstatus.reg_status_type_id

inner join  edcs_unistat.fee_cat_type feetyp
on          enrol.fee_cat_type_id = feetyp.fee_cat_type_id

group by    enrol.Rep_Start_Year, uni.university_code,  enrol.student_OEN

order by    enrol.Rep_Start_Year, uni.university_code, enrol.student_OEN
```

Comment: Add a GROUP BY institution

Comment: Which DBMS? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: As to your amended version: Where does uni suddenly come from? And you cannot access enrol.Rep_Start_Year as you do it, because there you don't select from enrol anymore, but from the unnamed derived table `(select enrol.student_OEN...)`.

Comment: The uni alias is defined later, as part of an inner join statement... is that okay? I was also thinking that select enrol.student_OEN is the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Actually all you forgot is the GROUP BY clause in your original query - which should be evident actually from the error message you got. Er, you got one, right? When you try to have non-aggregated values such as Institution together with aggregated ones such as COUNT(1), then the dbms tells you you cannot do so. Mihai is wrong however in so far as that you Need to Group by Institution plus the CASE Expression.

Comment: In order to join, give your derived query a name: `(select enrol.student_OEN...) students`. Then join uni `on uni.somecolumn = students.somecolumn`. To access the columns of the derived query also use that alias: `select students.Rep_Start_Year`. Make sure you select all columns in the derived table that you need from it. (Or just stick to your original query. As mentioned you only forgot the GROUP BY clause.)

Comment: The original query did have a GROUP BY clause, which I have added above. It also has a several INNER JOIN and WHERE clauses, which I suppressed for the sake of simplicity. Are the INNER JOIN and WHERE clauses supposed to be inside the nested SELECT?

Comment: Besides the Group by, you're also using double quotes around "other", they should be single quotes

Comment: So if you had a group by clause, what was your issue with your own query?

Comment: I've amended the original question to increase the code snippet. I'm still get the following error, which I believe is due to an invalid alias: "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: As I said: You derived table (sub-select) has no name. You select from <unnamed> and join with uniinst. In your ON clause you try to join uniinst with enrol. But there is no enrol! enrol is just a table alias *inside* your derived table query, i.e. inside the parentheses. Give your derived table a name, such as you did with your other derived table which you named uni.

Comment: I did realize, based on other posts in this forum, that the nested query needs a name, but I'm having trouble with the syntax. I'm revising a query that was created by someone else.

Comment: As I said: Just as uni. uni is a name for `(select u.UNIVERSITY_ID,
...)` put after the closing bracket. So simply give your `(select enrol.student_OEN...)` also a name in the same manner. And why do you cling so to that derived table thing? What was wrong with your originial query? What didn't work? The derived table here is just for the convenience not to have to type the CASE Expression twice, that's all.

Comment: BTW, as you are new: When answering my questions here, you should address me explicitely with @Thorsten Kettner. Otherwise I won't get informed. I just came back to see how you did, but I got no message. One only gets messages for comments to one's own requests or answers and when explicitely addressed as just shown.

Comment: Will do. I was able to resolve the issue by naming the sub-select. thanks for your help, @Thorsten Kettner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Institution, Student_Number, count(*)
from (select Institution, CASE WHEN Student_Number  not in ('999','000')
                            THEN "Other"
                          ELSE Student_Number
                          END as Student_Number
      from Enrolment)
group by Institution, Student_Number;
```

Comment: I have a feeling that this is correct, but I am getting an error message "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined". I've posted the code that is giving the error above.